# Google Actions Smarthome Oauth role confusion

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am studying the smarthome program belongs to Actions on Google([Official Overview](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/))

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K00u.png)

In the figure, google said that it need oauth2 authentication, but I have a question about what's the role of "Assistant Client App" in this oauth2 authentication procedure, is "Assistant Client App" the Third-party application so called in the OAuth2 model or other role?

Another question is that if the "Assistant Client App" is the Third-party application, does it mean that I have to build a Oauth server so the "Assistant Client App" can come and ask for the access grant?

Thank You for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Assistant Client app is the application on one's phone for the Google Assistant. In the settings one is able to set up a link to a smart home integration.

Comment: You are using OAuth to link your Smart Home integration with the user's Google account.